# How to fix "jQuery.Deferred exception"

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error: jQuery.Deferred exception: ARS is not defined ReferenceError: ARS is not defined at HTMLDocument. https://maiten.com/component/payplans/invoice/confirm/8O56WJCMALCI:908:36)

```
var total_all = total_price;
                        var tax_price = total_all * tax / 100;
                        total_all += tax_price;
                        total_all = total_all.toFixed(2);
                        total_price = total_price.toFixed(2);
                        $('span.currency-num').replaceWith("<span class='currency-num pp-payment-header-price pp-amount'> " + total_price + "</span>");
                        $(".pp-payment-header-price.first-amount span.pp-amount").text(total_all);
                        $(".tax-amount span.pp-amount").text(tax_price.toFixed(2));
                        createCookie('subtotal', total_price, 1);
```

How can I fix it? thanks

Comment: The exception indicates that there’s something wrong with an asynchronous operation with jquery’s internal implementation of promises. The code you posted doesn’t seem to have any relevant code that can trigger that error. Can you create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example?

Comment: Please update your question instead.